# How does overwrite existing insert mode work in redshiftcopyactivity for aws data pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl, amazon-data-pipeline

I am new to aws data pipeline. We have a use case where we copy updated data into redshift . I wanted to know whether I can use OVERWRITE_EXISTING insert mode for redshiftcopyactivity. Also, please explain the internal working of OVERWRITE_EXISTING.

Comment: i suggest you read / explore / try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html and then come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Data Pipelines are used to move data from DynamoDB or Amazon S3 to Amazon Redshift. You can load data into a new table, or easily merge data into an existing table.
"OVERWRITE_EXISTING", over writes the already existed data in to the destination table but with a constraint of unique identifier (Primary Key) in RedShift cluster. 
You can use "TRUNCATE", if you dont want your table structure to be changed due to the addition of PK.
Though, you can find things here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html